# Basic spec failing with Capybara / RSpec 3 / Rails 4 (have_content)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm relatively new to RSpec and Capybara, and I'm making a basic Comic Book Database Application to experiment with them.  For some reason the test is failing (though when I manually create a ComicBook I see the confirmation text).

Here is the test:

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'

feature 'Creating Comic Books' do
  scenario 'can create a comic book' do
    visit '/'

    click_link 'New Comic book'

    fill_in 'Title', with: 'Batman'
    fill_in 'Publisher', with: 'DC'
    fill_in 'Issue number', with: 32
    fill_in 'Summary', with: 'What a nice comic book'

    expect(page).to have_content("Comic book was successfully created.")
  end
end
```

And here is the failing message along with the backtrace:

```
1) Creating Comic Books can create a comic book
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Comic book was successfully created.")
       expected to find text "Comic book was successfully created." in "Toggle navigation Project name Home About Contact New Comic Book Title Publisher Issue number Summary What a nice comic book Back"
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:30:in `fail_with'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:37:in `handle_failure'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in `handle_matcher'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.1.2/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:54:in `to'
     # ./spec/features/creating_comics_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:152:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:152:in `block in run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:222:in `call'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:222:in `call'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.1.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:322:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:322:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:380:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:222:in `call'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:222:in `call'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:447:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:500:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:331:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:149:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:490:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:486:in `map'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:486:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:453:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `map'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:111:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:53:in `report'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:107:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /Users/esteban/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried using both capybara-webkit and selenium, I get the error regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't clicked the button to submit the form, in your test.

It will likely be something like `click_button "Create Comic Book"` after filling in the form.

Comment: Indeed I had not.  I guess I got confused because I already had ```click_link 'New Comic book'```  Thank you.